# What to Call Angular Markup In Html?

Tags: html, angularjs

This is a question about semantics. What do I call the 'angular markup' here?

```
<h1>{{someScopeObject.someProperty}}</h1>
```

What's the proper way to refer to this and things like ng-model/ng-bind. Or do I go with specific names and say "the ng-model attribute / directive" and there isn't anything generic?

Answer (score 2):

The double curly brackets are for data binding and what's inside the double curly brackets is an expression.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression